# CSS affect multiple objects simultaneously instead of individually

Tags: css

I'm encountering an issue with CSS when i am trying to move the different contents of my page. Because i need my project to be responsive with all screen sizes so am adjusting one at a time but it  seems to affect all objects on the page simultaneously, rather than just the intended object.
[For example here when i try to move the I feel part it moves the slide-bar and the write more about your feelings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Lym.png)

```
<div class="feelingText">
    <lable for="feelingText"> I feel</lable>
    <input type="text" id="feelingText" class="updatedText" name="feelingText" readonly style="width: 140px;">
    </div>
    <div class="textarea-title">Write more about your feelings</div>
    <div class="morefeelings">
<textarea type="text" id="moreFeelings" class="moreFeelings"  name="moreFeelings" resize="none"   placeholder="WRITE HERE..."></textarea></div>
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" class="slider" id="mySlider">
      <p>My mood: <span id="sliderValue">Neutral</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is part of the css:

```
.slider-container{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -150px;
  }
  .slider-wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    text-align: center;
   
  }
  
  .slider-wrapper p {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 280px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
  }
  
  .slider-wrapper .slider {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 400px;
    height: 15px;
    appearance: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000dca, #56608fb4, pink, #eeec90, #94ffa2);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    margin-left: 100vh;
    
  }
  
  .slider-wrapper .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    
  }
  
  #sliderValue {
    font-weight: bold
  }


.feelingText {
    display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  
}
.updatedText {
    font-size: 30px; 
    
}
.textarea-title{
  margin-top:-45vh;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 150px;
}

.moreFeelings{
    margin-left: 160px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 4em;
    width: 20em;
}
```

I been trying to adjust them with media queries for each screen size

Comment: Adjusting individuals components can be a pain and its very time-consuming, so I would suggest you use some kind of `CSS Layout system`, for example https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Is there something wrong in my code that affects moving them all together ?